# PHP: HTTP_Request2 gives zero content length

Tags: php, curl, pear, http-request

I want to POST using HTTP_Request2 Pear Class. I was succefull when I used cURL to do the same, but I dont get response data when I use HTTP_Request. It says content length as 0. I read the PEAR documentation for HTTP_Request2 and followed it to write the code. It will be of great help if someone points out my errors. cURL method works but HTTP_Request2 method dosent. What I think is that the HTTP_Request2 method is unable to post the data, but I am not sure about the header too. My code is

```
function header()
{
$this->setGuid(guid());
$this->header = array($this->service, 
time(), $this->getGuid());
return $this->header;
}

function header1()
{
$this->setGuid(guid());
$this->header = array('X-OpenSRF-service: '.$this->service, 
'X-OpenSRF-xid: '.time(), 'X-OpenSRF-thread: '.$this->getGuid());
return $this->header;
}
function toArray()
{
$url4 = urldata($this->method, $this->param);
return $url4; //returns an encoded url
}
function send1()
{
require_once 'HTTP/Request2.php';

//------cURL Method-------------------------
$endpoint = $this->endpoint;
$data = $this->toArray();
$header = $this->header1();
$url_post = 'http://'.$endpoint.'/osrf-http-translator';
$this->curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_post);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$this->server_result = curl_exec($this->curl);
if (curl_error($this->curl) != 0 ) {
$error = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($this->curl);
return $error;
}
var_dump ($this->server_result);
echo "<HR />";   

//-----HTTP_REQUEST2 Method---------------       
$request = new HTTP_Request2();
$request->setUrl($url_post);
$request->setHeader(array('X-OpenSRF-service' => $header[0], 'X-OpenSRF-xid' => $header[1], 'X-OpenSRF-thread' => $header[2]));
$request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);
$request->addPostParameter($data);
var_dump ($request); echo "<HR />";
$response = $request->send(); var_dump($response);
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly so it is more easy to read which hopefully will help to answer your question as it has quite some code.

Comment: Sorry, My code at http://pastebin.com/7pU9UG7r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the [`HTTP_Request2::send()`](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/docs/latest/HTTP_Request2/HTTP_Request2.html#methodsend) method is a little different to `curl_exec`. It is not as string, but another type, namely [`HTTP_Request2_Response`](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/docs/latest/HTTP_Request2/HTTP_Request2_Response.html).

To retrieve the response body as a string (a HTTP response contains the headers and a body), use the [`HTTP_Request2_Response::getBody`](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2/docs/latest/HTTP_Request2/HTTP_Request2_Response.html#methodgetBody) method:

```
...
$response = $request->send();
$responseBody = $response->getBody();
```

This should do what you're looking for, `$responseBody` then is a string. In more general terms: `HTTP_Request2` has an object-oriented interface. This allows to use different adapters (e.g. Curl as well as sockets or you can even write your own one, e.g. for testing) as well as retrieving the response body in a streaming fashion (e.g. with large responses you do not put all into a single string at once).

Comment: ...
$response = $request->send();
$responseBody = $response->getBody();
var_dump ($responseBody);     

is giving output as:   string(0) ""

Comment: Actually thats the problem I am facing, content length is zero!!

Comment: Than this needs further trouble-shooting. Please give a var_dump of all the response headers as well: `var_dump($response->getStatus(), $response->getReasonPhrase(), $response->getHeader());`